# insert statement in postgres for data type timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,

Tags: postgresql, pg

Database noob alert: 
I am trying to insert into a postgres table.
The field that I would like to insert in is called `make_date`.

The field type is `timestamp without time zone NOT NULL`,
How do I insert today's date in there? Like right now's date and time? Something like the below but I am unable to get the right datatype insert format for dateTime.now

```
insert into inventory_tbl (make_date) values (dateTime.now)
```

Comment: `insert into inventory_tbl (make_date) VALUES (now());` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In addition to C. Ramseyer's solution (which is right), if you always (or even usually) want `make_date` to be the date the record was created, you can set its default to `now()`:

```
alter table inventory_tbl alter make_date set default now();
```

Then if you don't include it in the list of columns in your insert, it'll be automatically set to `now()`:

```
test=> insert into inventory_tbl ( name ) values ('brick'), ('sand'), ('obsidian') returning *;
         make_date          |   name   
----------------------------+----------
 2013-03-21 09:10:59.897666 | brick
 2013-03-21 09:10:59.897666 | sand
 2013-03-21 09:10:59.897666 | obsidian
(3 rows)

INSERT 0 3
```

Answer (score 38):

Use `now()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.