# How to insert current datetime in postgresql insert query

Tags: postgresql, datetime, insert

```
INSERT into Group (Name,CreatedDate) VALUES ('Test',UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 1);
```

This is the query I have used for mysql to insert current date time.
When I am using this in postgresql, I am getting below error.

```
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function utc_timestamp() does not exist
SQL state: 42883
```

I have tried like below using `now()`, however it is inserting like `"2016-07-07 17:01:18.410677"`. I need to insert in `'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss tt'` format.

```
INSERT into Group (Name,CreatedDate) VALUES ('Test',UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 1);
```

How to insert current date time in insert query of postgresql in above format ?

Comment: Maybe search for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`or even `NOW()`. there are at least precision arguments to the former. So `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`will yield 3 subecond digits (milli second resolution)

Comment: ... Formatting via SET DATESTYLE eg. at: [in postgres, can you set the default formatting for a timestamp, by session or globally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723574/in-postgres-can-you-set-the-default-formatting-for-a-timestamp-by-session-or-g) or in the official postgres docs

Comment: `timestamp` columns do ***not*** have "a format". Any formatting you see is applied by the SQL client you are using. Change the configuration of your SQL client or use a proper formatting function if you want a different _display_ format.

Comment: Yes It ran on MySQL but now you want it to run in Postgresql so you need to look for the equivalent function in the Postgresql manual.

Answer (score 179):

`timestamp` (or `date` or `time` columns) do **NOT** have "a format".

Any formatting you see is applied by the SQL client you are using.

---

To insert the current time use `current_timestamp` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
INSERT into "Group" (name,createddate) 
VALUES ('Test', current_timestamp);
```

To *display* that value in a different format change the configuration of your SQL client or format the value when SELECTing the data:

```
select name, to_char(createddate, 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss tt') as created_date
from "Group"
```

---

For `psql` (the default command line client) you can configure the display format through the configuration parameter `DateStyle`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE

Comment: If I use this, I am getting bellow error as my date is timestamp format. column "createddate" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text

Comment: @Shesha Don't use that in the `insert` query. In your `insert` use `current_timestamp`

Answer (score 14):

For current datetime, you can use now() function in postgresql insert query.

You can also refer following link.

[insert statement in postgres for data type timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530899/insert-statement-in-postgres-for-data-type-timestamp-without-time-zone-not-null).

Answer (score 3):

You can of course format the result of `current_timestamp()`.
Please have a look at the various formatting functions in the official [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).